# ActiveMQ nonBlockingRedelivery broker/Spring configuration

Tags: spring, activemq-classic

I can't get the nonBlockingRedelivery property to actually work, and I can't figure out why. I must be missing something obvious.

If I try to set it up through the broker URL, for example;

> tcp://localhost:61616?jms.nonBlockingRedelivery=true

I will get the following error.

> Cause: Could not create Transport. Reason:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid connect parameters:
>   {jms.nonBlockingRedelivery=true}

If I try to set it up through Spring configuration, I will get the following error.

```
<bean id="connectionFactoryRedelivery" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.TransactionAwareConnectionFactoryProxy">
<property name="targetConnectionFactory">
 <bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
  <property name="brokerURL" value="${more.MQ.brokerURL}" />
  <property name="nonBlockingRedelivery" value="true" />
  <property name="redeliveryPolicy" ref="redeliveryPolicy" />
 </bean>
</property>
<property name="synchedLocalTransactionAllowed" value="true" />
</bean>
```

> org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid
>   property 'nonBlockingRedelivery' of bean class
>   [org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory]: Bean property
>   'nonBlockingRedelivery' is not writable or has an invalid setter
>   method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of
>   the getter?

Comment: What version of the broker are you using?

Answer (score 0):

My retarded error, I was using an old version of the JAR where this property actually did not exist. The above Spring configuration works 100%, and if you're having problems, they lie somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that I'm still seeing this issue with spring-boot-starter-activemq:1.5.10.RELEASE - in that this on spring.activemq.broker-url does not work:

```
?jms.nonBlockingRedelivery=true
```

However setting this property fixes it:

```
spring.activemq.non-blocking-redelivery: true
```